# SQL: CASE WHEN having AVG() as condition not giving right output

Tags: sql, sqlite, average

I have a table of unique users that each has a "rating" column (it's an average rating they give out of all their ratings given in a different table of reviews). I want to add another column to my table, which specifies either them giving a rating that is above the average of all ratings of all users (hence I use the AVG() function), below or at average (I call it "bias"). In other words, I want to see whether each user gives on average higher or lower ratings than the total average. I understand the limitedness of this query, and ideally I would include an interval (i.e. within 0.5 points below or above average still counts as average) but I can't seem to make even the simplest query work.

I've been using the Yelp dataset from a Coursera course, but I tried to create a sample that produces the same result that I do not want - just one row. I want to have this categorization for each row, hence it should return 3 rows in this example, "below average" in the first two and "above average" in the third. However, the code below produces just one row. I have been working with R and this seems like I am using incorrect syntax, but after 30 minutes of searching the web I cannot find a solution.

**I am working in and want to use SQLite syntax as part of the course in Coursera**

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
     id integer primary key, 
     rating integer
    );

INSERT INTO test
(id, rating)
VALUES
(1, 1);

INSERT INTO test
(id, rating)
VALUES
(2, 3);

INSERT INTO test
(id, rating)
VALUES
(3, 8);

SELECT id,
rating,
  CASE
    WHEN rating > AVG(rating) THEN "above average"
    WHEN rating < AVG(rating) THEN "below average"
    ELSE "no bias"
   END AS "bias"
FROM test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the aggregate function `AVG()` like this.
But you can do it with `AVG()` window function:

```
SELECT id,
rating,
  CASE
    WHEN rating > AVG(rating) OVER () THEN "above average"
    WHEN rating < AVG(rating) OVER () THEN "below average"
    ELSE "no bias"
   END AS "bias"
FROM test
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tLdjVUueWuaT25iPmSyxbF/0).
Results:

```
| id  | rating | bias          |
| --- | ------ | ------------- |
| 1   | 1      | below average |
| 2   | 3      | below average |
| 3   | 8      | above average |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
rating,
  CASE
    WHEN rating > (select AVG(rating) from test) THEN "above average"
    WHEN rating < (select AVG(rating) from test) THEN "below average"
    ELSE "no bias"
   END AS "bias"
FROM test
```

`AVG` is an aggregate function and works in conjunction with a `GROUP BY`.
when you do not specify anything in the `GROUP BY` section, it will aggregate the whole table thus reducing it to one row.

Generally you select aggregated columns and non-aggregated columns without specifying  the non aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` list. I am not a big fan of DBMS which allow  this behavior (SQLLite seems to be an offender).

What I did in the query above is that I calculated the average of the whole table using a subquery. And then compared each row against the average.

Or like others have specified you can go with WINDOW functions. Where you apply a function over a some parts of the data as defined by your window. They look like theri regular aggregated functions conunterparts but you will notice the `OVER` keyword which specify they are applied over a window. In the over clause you can partition your data or you can use it as a whole. For example if you had multiple stores and sales amount per day for each store, you could parition by store to compute the per store average.